# How do I generate "Smart Unit Tests" with Visual Studio 2015 Preview?

Tags: unit-testing, pex, visual-studio-2015

How do you generate "Smart Unit Tests*" with Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate Preview?

*Microsoft's S. Somasegar announced ["Smart Unit Tests"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/11/12/opening-up-visual-studio-and-net-to-every-developer-any-application-net-server-core-open-source-and-cross-platform-visual-studio-community-2013-and-preview-of-visual-studio-2015-and-net-2015.aspx) (Under the heading 'productivity') for Visual Studio 2015. This feature, based on Pex, uses code analysis to generate unit tests.

Comment: I can't find docs on it yet, but it appears that it works in C# by right clicking on a class or method name. I can't find it in VB.Net... probably not implemented for VB?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the link to msdn documentation: [Generate smart unit tests for your code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn823749%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation link you provided is useful, exactly what I needed. For those who want the TLDR version from the docs: "2. Right-click in a method in your code and choose Smart Unit Tests to generate unit tests for all the code paths in your method."

Comment: I just discovered the "smart Unit Tests" option is not available from directly within a unit test project. Once I right-clicked on a method in another project, I could see the option.

Comment: Alex: yes, this "smart test" option is available from the target class / method, not the unit test project. This feature will auto-generate unit tests for the target method and place them into a unit test project.

Comment: Does anyone know if xUnit will be supported in VS 2015 RC ?

Answer (score 7):

As of VS2015 Ultimate Preview we have not enabled this for VB.

Comment: Apologies for reviving an old thread -- do you think this will ever be enabled for VB.NET?